# Images Not Rendering Onto The Faces Of A Cube

Tags: rendering, image, faces

Newbie here with Blender, using version 3.1.2 - trying to get my head around the basics.

I've run into an issue where I'm trying to place five different images onto the inside faces of an open cube (I warned you it was basic!).

I've created five new material layers and assigned each one to each of the faces. I've replaced the base colour on each one with a different image, doing this in the shading workspace in exactly the same way.

When I view the preview in the shading workspace, it looks as I'd expect it to. But when I render the image, two of the faces are totally blank - the left one and the bottom one.

I've rechecked everything, including the UV Editing workspace and compared the blank side settings with the ones which are working, but I cannot see any difference at all with the parameters!

Has anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong? Cheers in advance - Graham

Comment: hello please pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please use (https://blend-exchange.com/) for sharing your blend-file. blend-exchange is dedicated to uploading files concerning posts at blender.stackexchange. This way you make sure, that the file will be present, when someone reads this thread in the future.

Comment: Any chance you have a second object hidden in the viewport?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.